# How can I link a content editor web part in Sharepoint to another URL link?

Tags: sharepoint, editor

In Sharepoint, how can I link an image in a content editor web part to another URL link by clicking on it?

I pasted my link into the Content Link space but when I apply the change it turns my image into a - and I cannot click the link

Answer (score 1):

a content editor webpart is just raw html. so the way to wrap an image in a link is to use the a (anchor) tag like so.

```
<a href="DestinationURL"><img src="yourimagefile.jpg" /></a>
```